# player heal function not working

Tags: python, function, if-statement

im trying to make a function that takes the players hp, max hp, and ammount heald and returns the new hp, but does not return a new hp higher than the max hp. i must have done the math wrong somewhere but dont know where.  my first attempt:

```
def heal(hp,max_hp,heal):
    if hp > heal:
        return (max_hp + heal)
    else:
        overflow = heal-max_hp
        new_hp = hp - overflow
        return (new_hp)

hp = heal(10,30,20)
print hp            #prints 20, should print 30
hp = heal(10,30,10)
print hp            #prints 30, should print 20
hp = heal(10,20,30)
print hp            #prints 0, should print 20.
```

my second attempt:

```
    def heal(hp,max_hp,heal):
    if hp > heal:
        return (max_hp + heal)
    else:
        overflow = max_hp - heal
        new_hp = hp - overflow
        return (new_hp)

hp = heal(10,30,20)
print hp            #prints 0, should print 30
hp = heal(10,30,10)
print hp            #prints -10, should print 20
hp = heal(10,20,30)
print hp            #prints 20, should print 20.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the healed hit points to the current hit points and then return the smaller of that value and the max hit points.

```
def heal(hp, max_hp, healed):
    return min(hp + healed, max_hp)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. Just add the healing value regardless then drop the hit points back to the maximum value if they exceed it:

```
def heal (hp, max_hp, heal):
    hp = hp + heal
    if hp > max_hp:
        hp = max_hp
    return hp
```

For what it's worth, both your solutions are defective if only because they contain:

```
return (max_hp + heal)
```

There should be *no* circumstance where you return something greater than `max_hp`. That's aside from the strange `if` conditions which I haven't analysed in depth because there's no need to - just use the code I provided above.

Comment: oh wow why didn't i think to use the max hp instead of trying to do other complex stuff that never works :P derp me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First add heal to hp, then if it exceeds max_hp, return max_hp:

```
def heal(hp,max_hp,heal):
    hp = hp + heal
    if hp > max_hp:
        return max_hp
    else:
        return hp
```

Comment: Oooh, I hate (with a vengeance) the `if..then return..else` construct. Just ditch the `else` altogether, it's not adding anything other than unnecessary indentation :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code may work:

```
def heal(hp,max_hp,heal):
    if hp + heal > max_hp:
        return (max_hp)
    else:
        return (hp + heal)
```

The new hp = current hp + heal, but can not beyond the max hp, so we compare the current hp + heal to max hp, then return the total hp of current hp plus heal, or max hp if they big than max hp.